# Require (only) one specific job in matrix to finish for other dependent job

Tags: github-actions

In [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions), imagine I have a build configuration like this, which builds my program on 3 different OSes and tests it on Ubuntu:

```yml
name: build-and-test

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]


  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
```

I would like the `test` job to [depend](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow) on the Ubuntu run from the `build` job. However, now it depends on all three. How can I specify that the `test` job only needs the ubuntu run from the `build` job to finish before it starts running, and not all three?

**TL;DR:** I would like the `test` job to run as soon as the Ubuntu build job is finished, and not wait on the macOS and Windows ones.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible based on the current implementation of GitHub Actions. My suggestion would be to pull out ubuntu into its own job, this way its execution is independent of the others.

```
name: build-and-test

jobs:
  build-slow:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [macos-latest, windows-latest]

  build-ubuntu:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-ubuntu
```

Reference: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25364#discussioncomment-4107131
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#handling-failures

Comment: Thanks, sad that's currently not possible.

I added a feature request for this feature here: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/42335

Comment: I upvoted it, I am in need of a similar feature and without it my workflow rewrite would be extremely tedious

Comment: I wish I could find explicit verbiage in documentation that spells out this idiosyncrasy, but I couldn't so if someone finds it feel free to append to my answer